# Read File and store into array and display sum in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get data from a file and store them in an array then display the data in a listbox the find then sum and display it in a text box. Here's my code and it doesn't work. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
private void findClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int sum;
   using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
   {
       if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
            using (StreamReader InputFile = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
            {
                while (InputFile.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    int[] array = new int[listBox.Items.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(listBox.Items[i].ToString());
                        array[i] = int.Parse(listBox.Items[i].ToString());
                        sum = array.Sum();
                        TotalAmtlabel.Text = sum.ToString("N0");

                        TotalNumberslabel.Text = listBox.Items.Count.ToString();
                        TotalAmountlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:N0}", sum);
                   }
               }  
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work". Don't expect people to run your code to find out for themselves. Describe *exactly* what's wrong and what you've already tried to find the cause.

Comment: When you have plan to read the file?

Comment: when I run the code, it doesn't display the data in the listbox and textbox. @ ChrisF @Xaqron

Comment: coz you have just opened the file but never read the data.

Comment: even when I use this code to read the file. It's doesn't still work. 
                            ////if (int.TryParse(InputFile.ReadLine(), out sum))
                            ////{

Answer (score 2):

```
listBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName));
```

Comment: Much more elegant solution to loading a file into a list but this doesn't answer the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and modify according to your needs:

```
string[] amounts = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
int currentSum = 0;
int totalSum = 0;
ListItem[] amountItems = new ListItem[amounts.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < amounts.Length; i++)
{
     if (int.TryParse(amounts[i], out currentSum))
     {
         totalSum += currentSum;
     }
     amountItems[i] = amounts[i];
}
listBox.Items.AddRange(amountItems);
TotalAmountlabel.Text = string.Format("{0}", totalSum);
```

You can also datasource to bind the list. Please go through below MSDN references once atleast to understand security cautions:

1. [ListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx)